# Deploy pyramid web app (apache/mod_wsgi)

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I`m trying to deploy a pyramid web application with apache and mod_wsgi, but I get error 500 with the message **DistributionNotFound: cloudy**

Anyone has any ideas? The project structure is something like this:

- cloudyapp

  - cloudy

    - static
    - templates
  - cloudy.egg-info
  - application.wsgi
  - production.ini

My Files

Application.wsgi

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/cloudyapp/')
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/www/cloudyapp/'

ini_path = '/var/www/cloudyapp/production.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

Production.ini

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.6-branch/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:cloudy

pyramid.reload_templates = false
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.6-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, cloudy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console

[logger_cloudy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = cloudy

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

apache conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cloudy.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cloudy.key

     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/cloudyapp/application.wsgi

     DocumentRoot /var/www/cloudyapp/
     Options -Indexes
     # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
     SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Figured it out. Posting it here in case anyone else is wondering. I forgot to run setup.py develop.

Comment: I am having this same problem, and cannot find a solution. Although I am trying to deploy my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Do you know whether it matters that you run `python setup.py develop` as opposed to `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you dont installed your pyramid app as for this you added app path to `sys.path`.
install your app via `setup.py` and put output of command `tail -n 30 /var/log/apache/error.log`